# python regex, optionally match a word

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex:

```
PackageQuantity:\b|Servings?PerContainer:\b|Servings?PerPackage:\b(\d+)
```

that supposed to match the following text:

```
ServingsPerContainer:about11
```

Blank white spaces are escaped for comfortability

the idea is, that the words `Package Quantity`, `Servings per container` or `servings per package` can be followed by any word (exactly one word), such as `approx.`, or `about`.

Seems simple enough, but I couldn't find a solution, since the regex above matches an empty string instead of the figure

pythonregex.com output:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("PackageQuantity:\b|Servings?PerContainer:\b|Servings?PerPackage:\b(\d+)",re.IGNORECASE)
>>> r = regex.search(string)
>>> r
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x672858ed0eef4da0>
>>> regex.match(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x672858ed0ee8c6a8>

# List the groups found
>>> r.groups()
(None,)

# List the named dictionary objects found
>>> r.groupdict()
{}

# Run findall
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'']

# Run timeit test
>>> setup = ur"import re; regex =re.compile("PackageQuantity:\b|Servings?PerContainer:\b|S ...
>>> t = timeit.Timer('regex.search(string)',setup)
>>> t.timeit(10000)
0.0259890556335
```

Comment: If you are down-voting a question, you may as well leave a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your regex, you are effectively matching:

- PackageQuantity:\b   **or**
- Servings?PerContainer:\b  **or**
- Servings?PerPackage:\b(\d+)

You'll note, the `\d+` is only attached to the last of those clauses.

Also, `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.  it will not match things like "about" or "approx".  `\w+` might be more like what you are looking for.  It matches letters, numbers and underscores.  Something like:

```
(PackageQuantity:\b|Servings?PerContainer:\b|Servings?PerPackage:\b)\w+
```

Comment: mhm, i wan to match the number, after these 1 word that suggests the accuracy of the number

Comment: In that case, in place of `\w+`, you could use `\w+\d` which will ensure there is at least one digit at the end of the word characters matched.  IN the case of "about11", the `\w+` would match "about1", and the \d would match "1", but unless you need to use capturing groups, that shouldn't matter.  If you do need to capture the accuracy word and digit separately using groups, you'd want to use something like:  `(\w+?)(\d+)` instead.

Comment: this worked for me, along with some python:
servings = ''.join(servings[-2:]) if servings[-2].isdigit()\
                    else servings[-1].strip()

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the optional word after the `:`

Either [(PackageQuantity:|(Servings)?PerContainer:|(Servings)?PerPackage:)[a-zA-Z.]*(\d+)](http://regex101.com/r/vT0uY6/1) or [(PackageQuantity:|(Servings)?PerContainer:|(Servings)?PerPackage:)(about|approx.)?(\d+)](http://regex101.com/r/hT0jP3/1) if your list of words is not too long should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `about` or `approx` in your pattern.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "ServingsPerContainer:about11"
>>> m = re.search(r'(?:PackageQuantity:\b|Servings?PerContainer:\b|Servings?PerPackage:\b)(?:about|approx)(\d+)', s, re.I)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f0531c7a648>
>>> m.group()
'ServingsPerContainer:about11'
>>> m.group(1)
'11'
```

OR

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(?:PackageQuantity:\b|Servings?PerContainer:\b|Servings?PerPackage:\b)\D*(\d+)', s, re.I)
>>> m.group()
'ServingsPerContainer:about11'
```

Comment: Thanks, but a large variety of words can occur there instead of `approx.` or `about` which are hardly an example